# Pass date to controller when move to Prev/Next FullCalendar jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have full calendar control in my view page and i want to pass week start date to controller when move to prev/next week. SO, i use it with following:

```
 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
   {
       header: {
           left: 'prev',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'next'
       },
       defaultView: 'basicWeek',

       events: function (start, end, callback) {
           $.get('events/get', function (result) {
               callback(result);
           });          

           startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').startOf('week');
          window.location.href = "/timesheet/index?selectDate=" + convertDate(startDate);          
       }
   });
```

But now it reloads the page continuously, where not able to view..
Can anyone help me to do this.. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
   {
       header: {
           left: 'prev',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'next'
       },
       defaultView: 'basicWeek',

       events: function (start, end, callback) {
           $.get('events/get', function (result) {
               callback(result);
           });         
       }
   }); 

    $('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {
        startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').startOf('week');
        window.location.href = "/TimesheetModels/EmpTimesheet?selectDate=" + convertDate(startDate);
    });
    $('.fc-next-button').click(function () {;
        startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').startOf('week');
        window.location.href = "/TimesheetModels/EmpTimesheet?selectDate=" + convertDate(startDate);
    });

    var stdate = $('#startDateCalendar').val();
    var testdate = new Date(stdate);
    if (Date.parse(testdate)) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', testdate);
    }
    else{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `location.href` will call itself again and again. So this is recursive process, to get rid of this process you need to make something static(not variables) but web storage like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) for egs,

```
....
startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').startOf('week');
if(!localStorage.getItem('isConvertedDate')){ // if key is not set and first time load
   localStorage.setItem('isConvertedDate',1); //set key, so that next time it will not refresh the page again
   window.location.href = "/timesheet/index?selectDate=" + convertDate(startDate);
} else {
   localStorage.removeItem('isConvertedDate');//remove if added
}
....
```